# Should rely on explain command when analyzing query efficiency?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization

```
explain  SELECT * FROM house JOIN street s on house.STREET_ID = s.ID WHERE s.type<>'out_of' AND street.DISTRICT_ID=4 ORDER BY house.num;
explain SELECT * FROM house JOIN street s on house.STREET_ID = s.ID WHERE s.type<>'out_of' AND house.DISTRICT_ID=4 ORDER BY house.num;
```

Type and district_id are compounds indexed in Street table
district_id is indexed in House table

1. explain with street.DISTRICT_ID=4, street table is joined

```
<data>
<row>
 <id>1</id>
 <select_type>SIMPLE</select_type>
 <table>street</table>
 <type>ref</type>
 <possible_keys>PRIMARY,FK_STREET_DISTRICT,IDX_STREET_DISTRICT_ID_STREET_TYPE</possible_keys>
 <key>IDX_STREET_DISTRICT_ID_STREET_TYPE</key>
 <key_len>8</key_len>
 <ref>const</ref>
 <rows>16</rows>
 <Extra>Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort</Extra>
</row>
<row>
 <id>1</id>
 <select_type>SIMPLE</select_type>
 <table>house</table>
 <type>ref</type>
 <possible_keys>FK_HO_ST,idx_or_st_entity</possible_keys>
 <key>FK_HO_ST</key>
 <key_len>8</key_len>
 <ref>street.ID</ref>
 <rows>70695</rows>
 <Extra></Extra>
</row>
</data>
```

2. explain with house.DISTRICT_ID=4

```
<data>
<row>
  <id>1</id>
  <select_type>SIMPLE</select_type>
  <table>house</table>
  <type>ALL</type>
  <possible_keys>FK_ST_HO,FK_ST_DISTRICT,idx_or_st_entity,IDX_HO_DISTRICT_NUM</possible_keys>
  <key>null</key>
  <key_len>null</key_len>
  <ref>null</ref>
  <rows>989734</rows>
  <Extra>Using where; Using filesort</Extra>
</row>
<row>
  <id>1</id>
  <select_type>SIMPLE</select_type>
  <table>street</table>
  <type>eq_ref</type>
  <possible_keys>PRIMARY</possible_keys>
  <key>PRIMARY</key>
  <key_len>8</key_len>
  <ref>house.STREET_ID</ref>
  <rows>1</rows>
  <Extra>Using where</Extra>
</row>
</data>
```

DISTRICT_ID is the same for house and street but the received estimated rows have a big difference. Does it mean that query with joined DISTRICT_ID is more efficient, where estimated rows = 70695?

Comment: In  recent versions of MariaDb you can use ANALYZE in place of EXPLAIN. It actually runs the query and gives live timings and actual row counts.  It's EXPLAIN ANALYZE iN recent versions of Oracle MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is actually examining an estimated 1,131,120 rows. For JOIN queries, you should look at the product of the `rows` field between the joined tables. In your case, it estimates it will examine 16 rows from `street`, and for each of these rows, it estimates it will examine 70,695 rows in the joined table `house`. 16*70695 = 1131120.

Whereas the second table estimates it will examine 989,734 rows in `house` (as a table-scan, indicated by `type: ALL`), and for each of the matching rows, it will look up 1 row in the joined table `street` by primary key (indicated by `type: eq_ref`).

Take the numbers with a grain of salt. They are only estimates, and they can be off by quite a bit. It's better to look at them not as precise numbers, but as orders of magnitude. I would consider both of them to be inefficient, unless you expect the final result of the query to have hundreds of thousands of rows.

Without seeing your tables, it's hard to guess at a better index strategy. Normally questions about query-optimization should include either a link to a [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/), or else the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table in the query.

I guess from your queries that both tables have a `DISTRICT_ID` column. Is that redundant, or can it be used to refine the join condition? For example:

```
... 
FROM house h JOIN street s 
ON h.STREET_ID = s.ID AND h.DISTRICT_ID = s.DISTRICT_ID
...
```

What I'm thinking is that if this can be used to narrow down the number of examined rows, it would be worth adding it to the index. But I can't know that given the limited information you've given about these tables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. DISTRICT is like 'tenant'. as you said they are both inefficient unless they expect a large number of records, unfortunately, they expect a large number of records so I would like to know which one is more efficient if it can be found out by looking at the 'explain' response. Is it possible to tell which one is more efficient if I'm working with a lot of records?

Comment: The EXPLAIN is one data point, but you should also just run the query and time it, or use MySQL's PROFILER feature. You might like my presentation [MySQL Query Patterns, Optimized](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-query-patterns-optimized) which shows examples of using the profiler and also session status to get row access counts.